# How to pass bytes parameter to contract method call using Web3.js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bytes

I'm trying to call a method in a contract and the method is like this:

```
function myMethod(uint8 tid, bytes calldata _bytes)
    public
    view
    returns (string memory)
{ ... }
```

I'm using **Web3.js** to call the methods and I have done successful ones on other methods but I can't find a way to pass bytes data to call this method. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

`bytes` is a variable type that holds a sequence of bytes from 1 to up to 32, you can read more about it in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays).

On Web3 you use [numberToHex](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#numbertohex) or [utf8ToHex](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#utf8tohex) for strings.

For example (a very general one), if your message is a string -

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
const method = contract.methods.MyFunction( web3.utils.utf8ToHex('my message') );
const txData = method.encodeABI(); 
const txConfig: TxData = {
    nonce,
    gasPrice,
    gasLimit,
    to: web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(RECEIVER_ADDRESS),
    value: 0,
    data: txData,
};
...
```

Comment: I used web3.utils.hexToBytes but didn't work

Comment: Use hex string `0x...`, added to answer. Would help if you stated what type you're trying to send.

Comment: The first parameter is uint8 which is the token id and the next one is an array of bytes (the bytes type in solidity)

Comment: @Kof this answer would be more helpful if you actually answered the question.

Comment: @NicSzerman I actually answered. Let me spell it out again `On Web3 you use numberToHex or utf8ToHex for strings.` - that's how you pass bytes parameter to a contract. If OP wants more a more specific answer, he should ask a more specific question, paste code, etc.

Comment: @Kof what should be the input to those functions? You are not answering the question, in the same manner that saying “You can use `web3.js`” also does not answer the question.

Comment: @NicSzerman it depends on what parameter he wants to send. If OP would've added concrete info, or even a code snippet, I'd be able to provide a concrete example.

Comment: Make up a few examples?

Comment: Added. @NicSzerman